# Is possible to use Auth0 server over HTTP intead of HTTPS?

Tags: http, security, web, https, auth0

Is possible to use Auth0 server over **HTTP** intead of **HTTPS**?

If yes, how to?

If not, why?

(I known the http is sniffeable)

Comment: Note that TLS is a requirement for OAuth2. (I don't know precisely what Auth0 does, but I imagine OAuth is a large part of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

A secure transport layer is required on all of the communication flows used in the authorization protocols supported by Auth0: OAuth2, OIDC, SAML and WS-Federation. This is to ensure the security of items such as credentials, tokens, and personally identifiable information.

HTTPS is also required on mandatory for the administration Dashboard and every related service. Again, it wouldn't make sense to exchange information used to secure systems over an insecure protocol.